# Filter Entity Framework with large string

Tags: entity-framework, filter

I have a `ListView` in a window in WPF. It is bind to Entity Framework and has `ItemsSource` with type of `List<Model.Asset_Asset>`. This window calls an advance search window and get a large string filter from it.

A simple output filter is here:

```
([barcode]  like 'bar12%' and ( [isParent]  = 'True' and ( [Name] like '%pr%')) and ( [Group]  = 'A'  or ( [Group]  = 'B')))
```

**Note:** The output filter is dynamic and may become very complicated.

Which way is better to use this large filter?

1. Change `ItemsSource` to `DataView` and filter it. Is it possible to change type of data in `DataView` to `Asset_Asset`?
2. pass the filter to Entity Framework . How can I do if it possible?
3. Make a `stored procedure` and pass filter to it. How to change type of `sp` to `Asset_Asset`?
4. Should I forget `EF` and use `DataView` to bind filtered list?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post. After these years I am strong enough to answer such questions.
So for anyone that may use answers:

Questions 1 and 2 and 4:
It is possible to use `dbContext` to execute sql query and return type.

Question 3:
In solution explorer find edmx file and go to properties. Double click on sp and select return type.